# Wordpress twentyseventeen theme header.php file data get automatically deleted

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

Whenever I am trying to edit any page from wp admin through WPBakery Page Builder, the header.php code gets auto deleted.

List of Plugins :
1.Advanced Custom Fields
2.Custom Post Type Maker
3.Disable Gutenberg
4.Gravity Forms
5.Gravity Forms + Stripe
6.Gravity Forms AWeber Add-On
7.OptionTree
8.Testimonial Slider
9.WPBakery Page Builder

I check the error_log.php file there is nothing on it.When true the WP_DEBUG a error appear on wp-admin not forntend.The Error : " Deprecated: Function create_function() is deprecated in /home/.../public_html/wp_wallstreet/wp-content/plugins/option-tree-master/includes/ot-functions-admin.php on line 69
".
I raise the php memory limit to 512M.

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '512M');
```

My header.php file code

```
<?php
/**
 * The header for our theme
 *
 * This is the template that displays all of the <head> section and everything up until <div id="content">
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-files/#template-partials
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Seventeen
 * @since 1.0
 * @version 1.0
 */

?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="no-js no-svg">
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<!-------------man_link_start----------------->
<link href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/css/responsiv.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/css/hover.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">  
<!-------------responsiv_menu_link_start----------------->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/css/styles.css?v=1.0" />
<!-------------slider_link_start----------------->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/engine1/style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/engine1/jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- End WOWSlider.com HEAD section -->    
<!-----------------------------carousel_start-------------------------------->
<link href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/css/carousel_css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
<!-------------smooth_scroll_link_start----------------->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Add smooth scrolling to all links
  $("a").on('click', function(event) {

    // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
    if (this.hash !== "") {
      // Prevent default anchor click behavior
      event.preventDefault();

      // Store hash
      var hash = this.hash;

      // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
      // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 800, function(){

        // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    } // End if
  });
});
</script>
<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body>
<!-------------header_start----------------->
<div class="header_wreper " >
    <div class="header_container">

        <a href="<?php echo site_url();?>"><div class="logo"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/images/logo.png" /></div></a>


      <div class="responsiv_menu">


        <div class="menu-container">
        <div class="crbnMenu">
            <div class="link-stack">

                <a id="nav-toggle" class="nav-toggle">
                    <span></span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <ul class="menu">
                <?php wp_nav_menu(array(
                   'menu' => 'Header Menu', 
                   'items_wrap'=>'%3$s', 
                   'container' => false,
                   'walker'  => new BootstrapNavMenuWalker()
                )); ?>

            </ul>

        </div>

    </div>

    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/js/crbnMenu.js"></script>
    <script>
        if ($(window)) {
            $(function () {
                $('.menu').crbnMenu({
                    hideActive: true
                });
            });
        }
    </script>



        </div><!--responsiv_menu_end-->



        <div class="destop_menu">
            <ul>
                <?php wp_nav_menu(array(
                   'menu' => 'Header Menu', 
                   'items_wrap'=>'%3$s', 
                   'container' => false,
                   'walker'  => new BootstrapNavMenuWalker()
                )); ?> 
                <a href="#" class="about_us_read_more" style="margin-top: 6px; padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
    height: auto;
    width: 90px;">Free Book</a>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div><!--header_container_end-->
</div><!--header_wreper_end-->
```

Comment: Please Can anyone guide me .

Comment: No idea but: event.preventDefault(); Breaks all versions of IE add a fallback whilst using this. Just a tip. Also try disabling all plugins bar the page builder and save, then enable 1 by 1 until you find the one deleting it.